# React-Native import/export library

Tags: react-native, import, export

so I am working on a React-Native app and I can't find proper library for import and export where i can select the directory i wanna save or chose my files.
I've already tried react-native-fs but it didn't quite do the job.

Basically I want something like pop box where I can select from where I want to import that file.